# meta_query is not working with tax_query as expected in WP_query

Tags: wordpress

SOLVED!

I have a custom post with some metabox and taxonomy. I'm trying to filter custom posts by combination of meta value and taxonomy and it's working as expected. When both meta value and taxonomy selected it's returning correct result, only taxonomy selection is also working. But if I select only meta value and try to filter post it's returning nothing. Here I'm sharing a video link of the output: https://youtu.be/XaCeJ_LcPhc. Is is possible to solve the issue without custom query?

```
$category_array= [];
$metabox_array = [];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){      
    if($key == 'ms_product_categories'){
        foreach($value as $cat_slug){
            array_push( $category_array, $cat_slug);
        }           
    }else{          
        array_push( $metabox_array, array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value ) );
    }
}       

if(count($metabox_array) >= 2){
    $relation = "'relation'=>'AND'";
}else{
    $relation = '';
}   

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ms_product',        
    'meta_query'  => array(
        $relation,
        $metabox_array
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'ms_product_categories',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category_array               
        ),
    )
);

$ms_products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Your tax query runs every time.  If you're only using meta_query, you need to make the tax_query go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot Howard. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, maybe it will be helpful for someone.

```
$category_array= [];
$metabox_array = [];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){      
    if($key == 'ms_product_categories'){
        foreach($value as $cat_slug){
            array_push( $category_array, $cat_slug);
        }           
    }else{          
        array_push( $metabox_array, array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value ) );
    }       
}

if(count($metabox_array) > 1){      
    $metabox_array['relation'] = 'AND'; 
}   
    
if(!empty($category_array)){                
    $tax_query = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ms_product_categories',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category_array,
            'include_children' => true,
        );      
}else{
    $tax_query = '';
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ms_product',        
    'meta_query' => $metabox_array,         
    'tax_query' => array(
        $tax_query
    )       
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I was conditionally adding meta and taxonomy to `$args` array. and no matter what I do `$post->request` would only print basic query without and of the "filter" condition.

I found out it was my silly mistake. just after `new WP_Query($args)` statement, I don't know why but I had written `wp_reset_query()` :D.

Just removed `wp_reset_query()`. and added `wp_rest_postdata()` after my loop and its ringing.

Took me 2 hours to figure it out...

Cheers!